# Rails default to a defined value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Hello I was wondering what the correct way to a defined default value as in

```
class SetDefault < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :table_name, :column_name, :type, default: "Your value"
  end
end
```

but instead of "Your Value" it was @yourvalue which is stored in a @settings model

```
 class SetDefault < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        change_column :table_name, :column_name, :type, default: @settings.yourvalue
      end
    end

class CreateSettings < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table
            t.string :yourvalue
         t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

@yourvalue would be defined and updated by a user

Comment: What is the source of that value? where do you store it once user enters it?

Comment: I eddited to include a settings model... this is purely hypothetical

Comment: `@settings` is a AR model row?

Comment: ar? i dont know what you mean

Comment: @JoeBloggs he meant ActiveRecord

Comment: then yes it is. A Setting Model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrations are normal Ruby classes. You can write Rails code within them. Eg. you can access your models.

```
class SetDefault < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
     change_column :table_name, :column_name, :string, default: Setting.find(1).yourvalue
   end
end
```

Replace `Setting.find(1)` with whatever logic you need to filter.

Comment: This seems like a dangerous way to do it. What would the value be for a dropped and reloaded DB?

Comment: we could wrap `Setting.find(1)` to check if the records exists before doing the change. else do a no-op migration

Comment: That's very true, but what's the advantage of storing that in the migration versus the class? I realise it was OP's question, but without advantages it seems needlessly dangerous

Comment: yes, that's what I said in my previous comment. we could check if it exists before doing the migration

Comment: Sorry, started writing that before the comment updated. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

I would set it on the model so your migrations remain non-reliant on previous states of the data therein.

```
class TableName < ApplicationRecord
  before_create :add_defaults

  # whatever

  private

  def add_defaults
    self.column_name = Setting.find(1).default_value unless column_name
  end
end
```

This way you won't be invoking ActiveRecord from the migration, and your app will still work if you deploy it somewhere and run the migrations before adding a `Setting` record. You'll likely need a fully-migrated database before adding any data.